# Proyecto ACM: Error: Android Source Generator

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Un amigo me ha pasado un proyecto para clase, y una vez importado el proyecto y la librería **ACM**, me dispongo a ejecutarlo, pero me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no se a que se debe.

Comment: Hola, ya tienes el SDK de android instalado? sino mira https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-android-development.html y si ya lo tienes instalado en la misma página sale como configurarlo https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html

Comment: He intentado configurar lo, pero no se como para arreglar el error realmente. He intentado configurarlo como pone la pagina pero nada.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079004/upgrade-intellij-to-10-5-and-android-build-fails-android-sdk-not-specified a ver

Answer (score -1):

El problema es que el proyecto que deseas abrir es un proyecto Android y debes especificar el SDK de Android.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si esta usando Intelli Idea, ve a `Project Structure` y definelo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa esta [**respuesta**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079004/upgrade-intellij-to-10-5-and-android-build-fails-android-sdk-not-specified) (inglés).

Aquí se tienen los requisitos para desarrollar Android con Intellij Idea.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/prerequisites-for-android-development.html

Comment: No tengo ningun Android 3.1, donde podria bajarmelo?

Comment: @VictorMatillaSanchez de el link indicado aquí https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/prerequisites-for-android-development.html al configurarlo simplemente lo seleccionas en tu proyecto.

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.